# Update rule and a ‘column reference is ambiguous’ error in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's create a table, add 2 rows and protect them from `update` action

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lists (
    list_id SERIAL,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO lists
    (name)
VALUES
    ('1'),
    ('2');

CREATE RULE list_upd_protect AS ON UPDATE TO lists WHERE list_id IN(1,2) DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

But `update` rule returns me an error:

`[42702] ERROR: column reference "list_id" is ambiguous Position: ...`

for `delete` It works good.

```
CREATE RULE list_del_protect AS ON DELETE TO lists WHERE list_id IN(1,2) DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

Can you explain me an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an UPDATE rule you can reference the old and the new values and you need to tell Postgres which one you mean:

```
CREATE RULE list_upd_protect 
    AS ON UPDATE TO lists 
   WHERE OLD.list_id IN(1,2) DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
         ^ -- here
```

In a DELETE rule there is only the "old" value available, so the reference is not ambiguous.